# Having Multiple authors for the same WordPress Plugin

Tags: plugins, author

Is it possible to have more than one author for a WordPress plugin using the plugin comment block? I searched for it, but I think it's not possible through the default way. Is there a workaround for this?

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: Name Of The Plugin
 * Plugin URI: http://URI_Of_Page_Describing_Plugin_and_Updates
 * Description: A brief description of the Plugin.
 * Version: The Plugin's Version Number, e.g.: 1.0
 * Author: Name Of The Plugin Author
 * Author URI: http://URI_Of_The_Plugin_Author
 * License: A "Slug" license name e.g. GPL2
 */
```

Comment: A quick look at the code, I think you may have some luck by using the filter 'plugin_row_meta'. Used in: /wp-admin/includes/class-wp-plugins-list-table.php at line 552

Comment: You can add a lot of authors, but only one author URI and I think, that is your problem? If you will solve this topic then is this possible via a filter, like `plugin_row_meta`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys, I will try to play with this filter and update the question with my best result.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try

1) First add new headers for the plugin meta:

```
add_filter('extra_plugin_headers', 'add_extra_headers');

function add_extra_headers(){
return array('Author2');
}
```

2) Next filter the authors meta row on output:

```
add_filter('plugin_row_meta', 'filter_authors_row_meta', 1, 4);

function filter_authors_row_meta($plugin_meta, $plugin_file, $plugin_data, $status ){

if(empty($plugin_data['Author'])){
    return $plugin_meta;
}


if ( !empty( $plugin_data['Author2'] ) ) {
    $plugin_meta[1] = $plugin_meta[1] . ', ' . $plugin_data['Author2'];
}


return $plugin_meta;
}
```

3) When you create the plugin add the new meta key and value..example:

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: My Plugin
 * Plugin URI:http://myplugin.com
 * Description: My Plugin is the Best!
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: <a href="#">Author One Name</a>
 * Author2: <a href="#">Author Two Name</a>
 */
```

Answer (score 2):

David's solution didn't work for me, but I was able to do part of what he did and put links directly in the author field.

```html
    Author: <a href="#1">Author 1</a>, <a href="#2">Author 2</a>
```

Comment: A much simpler solution that seems to work great. Thanks!